# Can I charge a 4.2 V battery with a 5 V adapter?

Tags: gsm, usb, battery

Can I charge a 4.2 V battery with a 5 V adapter without damaging the battery?

Comment: What type of battery is it, this will help you get a better answer.

Comment: Welcome to Arduino SE. I'm going to close this as off-topic because the question doesn't seem to involve Arduino at all. If it's supposed to be about Arduino then feel free to edit the question and we can re-open it.

Answer (score 2):

This question would be a better match to the Stack Exchange Electrical Engineering group.

A 4.2V battery is very likely a LiIon or LiPo battery. I'll call it LiPO below as it's easier to type.

Most cellphones and many small electronic device use a single LiPo battery and use a 5V input to charge them. To do this they have internal control circuitry that ensures the battery's specifications are met. You can obtain suitable control electronics (in many cases as a single IC requiring maybe a few external resistors to configure it) and it makes great sense to use such a control circuit.

In an emergency you can use a 5V source to charge a 4.2V battery **IF** you know what you are doing and are able to ensure the battery specifications are adhered to. Failing to stay "in spec" may lead to the traditional LiPo "vent with flame" response, and even if there is no apparent damage the battery life can be greatly or very greatly reduced by out of spec treatment.

Key requirements are:

- NEVER exceed 4.2V at battery terminals.
- NEVER exceed Ichg_max = manufacturers max charging current.
  This is usually the same value in mA as the battery capacity in mAh.
  ie 1000 mA for a 1000 mAh battery
  3300 mA for a 3300 mAh battery etc
- When charging, EITHER stop charging when battery potential reaches 4.2V OR if you are able to hold the battery AT 4.2V, then stop charging when Ichg falls (under battery control) to say Ichgmax/4.
- If Vbattery is under 3.0 V (which it NEVER should be) charge at no more than C/10 (eg  for a 1000 mAh cell) until Vbattery rises to >= 3.0V. If the battery will not rise to 3.0V under C/10 charge it is dead.

IF you can satisfy ALL these requirements at all times you can charge a LiPo or LiIon battery from 5V without a special charger.

Answer (score 1):

No. You must use a charger properly designed for the battery; attempting to connect a Li-ion battery directly to a USB charger will damage the battery, possibly catastrophically.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KWo4aDNnZT8

Comment: @Magic-Mouse The video is lots of fun, but does not address the issues involved. See my answer for details.

Comment: It does not address the issues, but it proves that LIPO is not a toy. And should be treated as if not.